# Installshield MSI not killing running process on uninstall

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

I have an Installshield 2010 Basic MSI.  It installs a windows exe that runs in the system tray.  On uninstall, the exe is deleted but if the process is running in the system tray it continues is not killed.  There are no warnings or errors by the installer that informs the user that the process is in use.

How can I make installshield kill the process if before removing its exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write a custom action to either send the EXE a message to shutdown gracefully or you have to write a custom action to terminate the process.  (Less ideal depending on what the program is doing and you'll get the annoying ghost icon in the tray until you mouse over it. )

How you do this depends on which route you take and what language you want to use to write the custom action.  C++ / C# dll, InstallScript CA, VBScript CA or even EXE CA.